# Highcharts - Render data-table with graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've been working on a way to render the data shown in a chart in a table below - above or next to the relevant chart.

I've been having a hard time so I've been looking for examples, most relevant examples link me to the forums of highcharts which is no longer supported and some topics no longer exist.

I would like to know if there is a way (hack?) to show tables rendered with the chart, containing the data of that chart.

Comment: i dont get you? on [highcharts demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) website on any charts you can click on "View Option" or "edit in jsffidle" and see how data for charts look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can get at the data used in the chart using:

```
chart.series[0].data
```

(this gets the data array for the first series).

You could then iterate over this data, adding each item as a 'td' to a table row.